# Open XML SDK - Part Root Element is null

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to read and edit CoreFilePropertiesPart of an Excel file. When accessing the RootElement property of the part it shows null. Obviously the part is not null. Viewing the xml file shows the following root element:

```
\<cp:coreProperties ... \</cp:coreProperties\>
```

Did Microsoft forget to implement this or is there another way to access data in this part?
I'm using DocumentFormat.OpenXml 3.0.0-beta0003

I'm able to read the CoreFilePropertiesPart data via OpenXmlReader, but using reader requires extra handling, parsing etc. It would be more convenient to have access to the object instead.

Comment: How are you accessing the `RootElement`? Kindly share your code to help us understand the problem better.